# Windows 10 batch files: Weird behaviour on files that worked in previous versions

Tags: batch-file

So I have the following batch file, which launches a game server for [Sauerbraten](http://sauerbraten.org/):

```
@ECHO OFF

set SAUER_BIN=bin

IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "amd64" (
    set SAUER_BIN=bin64
)
IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%" == "amd64" (
    set SAUER_BIN=bin64
)

start %SAUER_BIN%\sauerbraten.exe "-q$HOME\My Games\Sauerbraten" -gserver-log.txt -d %*
```

The batch file comes by default with the game install, and worked fine on Windows 7.

When I run it as admin, I get the following error in a popup window:

```
Windows cannot find 'bin64\sauerbraten.exe'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again.
```

I have verified that the file is there and that the spelling is correct.

In the same directory, there is another batch file to launch the game itself, which is identical except for a couple of launch parameters in the last line. When run, it works fine. I have copy-pasted this file into the other and made the changes visible in case there were invisible characters or anything, but that made no difference.

```
@ECHO OFF

set SAUER_BIN=bin

IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "amd64" (
    set SAUER_BIN=bin64
)
IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%" == "amd64" (
    set SAUER_BIN=bin64
)

start %SAUER_BIN%\sauerbraten.exe "-q$HOME\My Games\Sauerbraten" -glog.txt %*
```

When not running as admin, the server actually seems to launch (as it outputs to the log file and gives an error stating it could not create the server host, which I suspect to be associated with needing to run as admin).

Why am I seeing this behaviour? I can't think of any reasonable explanation.

Comment: So you are saying, if you run the second script as __admin__ it does work? Does not seem right as both should fail seeing that admin would need startup in `c:\windows\system32` and the `bin` and `bin64` directories does not exist there... anyhow, add this `%~dp0` after start, as `start "%~dp0%SAUER_BIN%\sauerbraten.exe "-q$HOME\My Games\Sauerbraten"  -gserver-log.txt -d %*` and see what happens?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard if you start a program with quotes then you must include a dummy quote as the first argument `start "" "%~dp0%SAUER_BIN%\sauerbraten.exe "-q$HOME\My Games\Sauerbraten" -gserver-log.txt -d %*`

Comment: @phuclv yes I am aware. I was mostly referring to `%~dp0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon how your executable accepts its arguments, I'd suggest either:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SAUER_BIN=bin"
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set "SAUER_BIN=bin64"
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%==64 Set "SAUER_BIN=bin64"
Start "" "%~dp0%SAUER_BIN%\sauerbraten.exe" -q"$HOME\My Games\Sauerbraten" -g"log.txt" -d"%*"
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SAUER_BIN=bin"
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 Set "SAUER_BIN=bin64"
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%==64 Set "SAUER_BIN=bin64"
Start "" "%~dp0%SAUER_BIN%\sauerbraten.exe" "-q$HOME\My Games\Sauerbraten" "-glog.txt" "-d%*"
```

I have no control over your additional arguments, so you'll have to decide whether it should read `"%*"` or `%*`.